# How can I suppress records with changes in fields I don't care about in a continuous Streaming job in Apache Flink?

Tags: apache-kafka, duplicates, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I'm trying to understand why when working with an `upsert-kafka` source in my job I see records that are essentially duplicates.

Suppose I have an `organizations` table source that's reading from a Kafka topic, defined like this...

```
CREATE TABLE `organizations` (
    id BIGINT,
    uuid STRING,
    user_count INT,
    -- lots of other fields
    PRIMARY KEY (id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
    'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
    'key.format' = 'avro-confluent',
    'value.format' = 'avro-confluent',
    'topic' = '...'
)
```

It's being populated by a Kafka Connect instance running a Debezium postgres connector reading from the DB.  But *most* of the records that go into the Kafka topic are changes to the `user_count` field and nothing else.

I've created job which reads from this topic and writes to another `upsert-kafka` topic
with this implementation

```
@Override
public void populateStatementSet(StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv, StatementSet statementSet) {
    var result = tableEnv.sqlQuery("SELECT DISTINCT id, uuid FROM organizations");
    statementSet.addInsert(SINK.name, result);
}
```

My expectation is that if a record comes from the `organizations` table/topic, and the field changed isn't either `id` or `uuid` that it should produce no output, and not put a record into the output topic.  But the actual behavior is that every incoming record in the Kafka topic produces an output record, even if it's identical to the last record produced.

Is there no way to get the streaming job to simply drop records that are effectively unchanged?